# why an odd fix for spacing on an f-string

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, spacing, functools, f-string

Went on a break and decided to tweak my 2 second decorator, in anticipation of an early early Spring (cross your fingers). Twenty minutes after adding umbrellas (you might have to replace them with another UTF-8 character), the first line was driving me nuts, no matter what 'I wish it worked this way' stuff I threw at the string.

Finally, using the `+` operator (the second line) fixed my problem, even though it couldn't be used in the first separation. So, I ask you: Why is the spacing off at all (when both concatenation operators are the same), and, well, why does this non-standard approach work?

```
from functools import wraps

def dasher(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        brella = '\U00002602'
        print(f"{brella} #", f"{brella} # "*8, f"{brella}")
        print(f"{brella} #", f"{brella} # "*8 + f"{brella}") # concat and crazy
        # print("\U00002602 #","\U00002602 # "*8,"\U00002602")
        # print(f"\U00002602 #",f"\U00002602 # "*8,f"\U00002602")

        print()
    return wrapped

@dasher
def dashed():
    pass

dashed()

☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ #  ☂
☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂
```

**Pythonic Refactoring**

Thanks to Chris Doyle's answer in the comments, following an explanation of spacing differences between `,` and `+`, the following dirties things up again with some complexity, but extends usability, illustrating spacing while avoiding the need for `sep=''`.

```
print(' # '.join(brella*3), '#' ,' xx '.join(brella*5) , '#' ,' # '.join(brella*3))
print(' # '.join(brella*3) + ' o ' +' xx '.join(brella*5) + ' o ' +' # '.join(brella*3))
```

With output:

```
☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ xx ☂ xx ☂ xx ☂ xx ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂
☂ # ☂ # ☂ o ☂ xx ☂ xx ☂ xx ☂ xx ☂ o ☂ # ☂ # ☂
```

Comment: when you pass multiple items to print (I.E seperated by comma by default print will put a space between them). So when you multiply your inner brella you end each string with a space, then you use a `,` So print will put another space in

Comment: So to be clear, the `,` is not a concat operator. Print is a a function in python 3. So calling `print("foo", "bar")` is passing 2 string arguments to print . print function will then join these with the value of `sep` which by deafult is a space unless you change it. calling print("foo" + "bar") will result in two strings being first concat together then a single string argument being passed to print. So `,` and `+` are not both concatenation operators here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass multiple items to print by deafault print will use space as the seperator. So when you give your first string you end it with a `#`. you then follow this with a comma and pass in your next item to print(So since the default separator for items in print is space the first item and second item will be separated by a space. So you will have `hash` `space` `umbrella`

however your second string which you multiply ends in a space. you then give  a comma then your third item. So your second item ends with a space then print will put in a space between your second and third item. resulting in you having a double space. so you will have `hash` `space` `space` `umbrella`

If you dont want this behavior, manually put in the space at the end of your first item to make it consistent like your second item which ends with a space and then at the end of your print set the separator as an empty string.

Alternatively you can just multiply your `brella` by 10 and then use " # " as the joiner to connect them all.

```py
brella = '\U00002602'
print(f"{brella} #", f"{brella} # "*8, f"{brella}")
print(f"{brella} #", f"{brella} # "*8 + f"{brella}")
print(f"{brella} # ", f"{brella} # "*8, f"{brella}", sep='')
print(' # '.join(brella*10))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ #  ☂
☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂
☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂
☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂ # ☂
```

Comment: Thank you. `sep=''` was wholly absent from my thinking. The explanation is great and very usable.

Comment: Of course you could write this all much more concisely by just multiplying brella by 10 then using " # " as the joiner between them `print(' # '.join(brella*10))`

Comment: That feels a lot more pythonic and flips the quick and dirty approach on its head for being quick -- and clean.